# allowsAirPlayVideo property on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, avplayer, airplay

Does anyone know what are supposed to be used do disable AirPlay video playback on iOS 6.0?

I tested in iOS 6.0 and 5.1 and still working.

At this moment i'm using allowsAirPlayVideo = NO, but on iOS 6 it's Deprecated according the Apple Documentation:

[Deprecated AVPlayer Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Not the only thing missing from the online documentation! There are three deprecated AVPlayer methods in iOS 6:

```
airPlayVideoActive
allowsAirPlayVideo
usesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive
```

It seems they have been replaced with:

```
externalPlaybackActive
allowsExternalPlayback
usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive
```

Information gleaned from [this set of diffs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/).
(Hello Apple? You could do better than that!)

Answer (score 4):

The property you should set is `allowsExternalPlayback` in iOS 6 instead of `allowsAirPlayVideo` from iOS 5.

Comment: This property seems to be missing from the online documentation.